# Firebase Auth how to check if the user is Signed Up or Logged In?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication, firebase-authentication

I want the user to **Signup** then **Login** and only when he/she is **Logged In** then I want to show the `HomeScreen` but when I **Signup** and hot restart It will immediately redirect the user to `HomeScreen` instead of `LoginScreen`. How can I solve this problem?

```
        class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
        const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

        @override
        State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
      }

      class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
              body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const ErrorScreen();
              } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null) {
                return const SignUpScreen();
              }
              return const HomeScreen();
            },
          ));
        }
      }
```

Comment: Try calling ```FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()``` after the user does signUp.

Answer (score 0):

to create a new user you can use the function:
`FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword( ... )`
then after create an account you can use the function:

```
.whenComplete()
```

Example:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword().whenComplete((){// navigate to your desire page})
```